# PHP & SQL. Basic Code doesnt work. create empty divs and fills the ones that match with the ID

Tags: php

I want to create 8 Divs, get info from the DB and fill those that match with the DIV number. so for example in the db i have 2 rows with positionid of 3 and 5.

The script will create 8 divs as stablished. and only fill the 3th and 5th with the rest of information of the row  . the rest of the divs will be empty but still exist and in the correct order.

I made some code and tried to make it work but it doesnt.

Here is the code :

```
<?php

//Step2
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');


//Step3
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) || $count < 8) {


while($count != (int) $row['posicion']){
    echo $element;
    $count++;
}

    echo $row['posicion'] . ' ' . $row['nombre'] . ': ' . $row['descripcion'] . ' ' . $row['fecha'] .'<br />';

    $count++;
}
//Step 4
mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Any idea why? cheers

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"... what does it do  that it isn't supposed to? and what does it not do? also, this "||" means or.. so, while fetching row, or count is less than 8... are you sure it's not supposed to be AND, rather than OR?

Comment: I don't see any DIVs being created here. How are you planning to create those DIVs here?

Comment: where should `$element` come from? it's never defined.

Comment: also `$count` is not defined before you use it.

Comment: Please share your div content if possible. Or at least show us the structure of the div content.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla";
```

Are you sure that's not a typo? Or should it be `table` instead of `tabla`
?

Comment: `table` would not work (without escaping). It's a reserved word.

Comment: and as you can see in the naming of the fields, that OP speaks spanish/portugese. So `tabla` seems to be on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a simplified version of your code. Please take a look if you makes sense to you:

```
<?php

function render_div($row = null) {
    $row_data = 'EMPTY DIV';

    if ($row) {
        $row_data = $row['nombre'] . '<br>' . $row['descripcion'] . '<br>' . $row['fecha'] . '<br>';
    }

    echo "<div>$row_data</div>";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');


for($i=0; $i<8; $i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($i == (int) $row['posicion']) {
        render_div($row);
    }
    else {
        render_div();
    }
}

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Comment: nice one, but it doesnt work as intended. basically this happens. 3
EMPTY DIV2
6
EMPTY DIV2
0
EMPTY DIV2
0
EMPTY DIV2
0
EMPTY DIV2
0
EMPTY DIV2
0
EMPTY DIV2
0
EMPTY DIV2

Comment: Please share your div content! It would be easier to understand!

Comment: if($i == (int) $row['posicion']) {
  //DB entiry's posicion field has a match
  //render your div with row information


  print '<div>';
  print $row['nombre'];
  print '<br>';
  print $row['descripcion'];
  print '<br>';
  print $row['fecha'];
  print '<br>';
  print '</div>';

 }
 else {
  print '<div>EMPTY DIV2</div>';
 }

Comment: shouldnt it be a WHERE in the SQL?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please take a look!

Comment: doesnt work, the db has 2 registry. one of posicion: 3 and other of posicion: 5 . posicion is int on the db itself, could it be because of that? The result is : EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV

Comment: it fails at the if, and goes to the else all the time-   if($i == (int) $row['posicion']) {
  render_div($row);
 }

Comment: Could you print `$row['posicion']` in the loop and let me know please? That  looks like a data issue now.

Comment: here it is:  3
EMPTY DIV
5
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV

Comment: fixed it. it was  $query = "SELECT * FROM misiones WHERE posicion = $i";

Comment: OK great to know that! If my solution helped you then please do not forget to accept/upvote it! :)